# javascript worker loop ajax

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am having a worker which has an array of urls. I loop through these URLs and throw an AJAX call, but inside success method of ajax when I send message back to website, it always sends the last request.

**app.js**

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
var urls = ['url1','url2','url3'];
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker: ', e.data.url);
}, false);

worker.postMessage({"args":[urls]});
```

**worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    function load(url){
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                console.log(xmlhttp);
                self.postMessage({'url':url});
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    var urls = e.data.args[0];
    for(var i = 0; i<urls.length; i++){
        load(urls[i]);
    }
}, false);
```

Now inside `console.log();` of app.js, the output is only of the last url.

I don't get all all URLs response.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Dear downvoters, please add comment before downvoting. At least I ll learn from that and next time wont repeat it again if the question is worth downvoting.

Comment: I totally agree.  The questions I find interesting to solve, often get downvoted.  Usually I think it's lazy and cowardly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is real easy. make line 3

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

What you're doing now, is setting xmlhttp as a global variable.  This means overriding the variable every time line 3 is executed.

Comment: Are you sure?  What I think was your problem, is solved with the extra var.  Make sure you clear all the cache (Ctrl + F5) ; maybe it's loading the cached code, or something.  Or maybe explain your question a little more thoroughly

Comment: I did, I am getting same output, I guess I need to implement promise.